# Send reset_password_token in the email in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using devise for authentication. What I am trying to do is send a reset_password_token in the link which is sent to the user. I am creating an agent from ActiveAdmin portal once it is created I am sending a link to the agent's email address so they can reset their password but I am not able to figure out how to send the reset_password_token with the link which is sent to the agent. Please have a look at the code below and help me find the solution

organisation_mailer.rb

```
class OrganisationMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'abc@yahoo.com'

  def send_link(agent_id)
    @agent = Agent.find(agent_id)

    token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    @agent.update(organisation_token: token)
    @link = "#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]}/organisation?token=#{token}"

    mail to: @agent.email, subject: "On boarding link for #{@agent.full_name}"
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
get 'organisation', to: 'agents#organisation', constraints: ->(req) { req.format == :json }
```

agents_controller.rb

```
  def organisation
    return if params[:token].blank?

    @agent = Agent.find_by(organisation: params[:token])
    sign_in(@agent, scope: :agent)
  end
```

agents.rb

ActiveAdmin.register Agent do

```
action_item :send_email, only: :show do
 link_to 'Send Email', send_email_admin_agent_path, method: :post
end  

member_action :send_email, method: :post do
    OrganisationMailer.send_link(resource.id).deliver_now
    redirect_to admin_agent_path(resource.id), notice: 'Organisation link has been sent'
end
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling the wrong method here: `OrganisationMailer.send_organisation_link(resource.id).deliver_now` but your method is named `send_link`

Comment: And in your routes you're missing an `s`: `agent#organisation` instead of `agents#organisation`

Comment: @benj-p sorry about that. it was a typo when I was adding code to stackoverflow